# Searching a string for a variable substring in a certain format

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, find, string-formatting

Imagine I'm trying to find a substring formatted as **"X.X.X"**, in which the Xs can be any integer or character, in a string. I know that in Python I can use `string.find("whatever")` to find some substring within a string, but in this case, I'm looking to find anything that is in that format.

For example:

Say I have the string "Hello, my name is John and my Hotel room is **1.5.3**, Paul's room is **1.5.4**"

How do I go about finding "1.5.3" and "1.5.4" in this case?

Comment: The keyword is `regex`. Search for it, and I'm sure you will be able to do it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to search for a pattern and not a known string, you may use `regex` with python package `re` and here method `findall` would fit

You need to pass it your pattern, here `\w\.\w\.\w` would be ok, `\w` is for a letter or digit, and `\.` for a real point

```
import re

value = "Hello, my name is John and my Hotel room is 1.5.3, Paul's room is 1.5.4"
result = re.findall("\w\.\w\.\w", value)
print(result) # ['1.5.3', '1.5.4']
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I'm looking for. Just to clear some things up, imagine that in the last section the format has two digits, say like "X.X.XX", would that still be the same?

Comment: @Hasake `\w` would fit for one only, you can do `\w+` for '1 or more' or `\w{1,2}` for "1 or 2"